# Adding Quarterly totals to Yearly stacked column

Tags: r, ggplot2, text, geom

I have a very simple data set that has 3 columns: Year, Quarter and Net_Amount. I can create a simple 3 column chart based on year using R, but as soon as I try to add the quarterly data AND add the totals by quarter to the chart, all of the totals, get squashed together on 1 line. This is my code to generate the stacked column chart in R. Here is a small subset of my data

Year  Quarter  sum_total
         
1 2020  Q1               0
2 2020  Q2               0
3 2020  Q3               0
4 2020  Q4      1597856189
5 2021  Q1       464188929
6 2021  Q2       499179243
7 2021  Q3       570470331
8 2021  Q4       605997816
9 2022  Q1       654494589
10 2022  Q2       654494579
11 2022  Q3       654494599
12 2022  Q4       654494589

```
dput(df)
three_yrqtr_df <- df %>% 
    # change the fiscal_year to character type
    mutate(Year = as.character(Fiscal_Year)) %>%
    select(Year,Quarter,Net_Amount) %>%
    
    group_by(Year,Quarter) %>%

    summarize(sum_total = sum(Net_Amount))
three_yrqtr_df

ggplot(three_yrqtr_df,
   aes(x=Year, 
       y=sum_total,
       fill=Quarter,
       label = dollar(sum_total)),
   vjust = 0.5,
   check_overlap = T) +
geom_col(position="stack", color = "black") +
geom_text(aes(x=Year, y = sum_total),vjust = -1) +
scale_y_continuous(labels = label_number_si())
```

#here is my solution:
ggplot(three_yrqtr_df,
aes(x=Year,
y=sum_total,
fill=Quarter,
label = dollar(sum_total),
group = group),
vjust = 0.5,
check_overlap = T) +
geom_col(position="stack", color = "black") +
geom_text(aes(label=dollar(sum_total)),
position = position_stack(vjust = 0.9)) +
stat_summary(fun = sum,
aes(label = dollar(..y..),
group = Year,
vjust = -1),
geom = "text") +
scale_y_continuous(labels = label_number_si())

[image]

Comment: Please use `dput` to provide us with a dataset that we can use to run this, and modify it to answer your question.

Comment: how do I use dput to add my dataset?

Comment: `dput(df)` yields the code necessary to produce `df`.

Comment: i can see it run in R Studio, but how does that help you here?

Comment: I resolved my issue. Here is my code

ggplot(three_yrqtr_df,
       aes(x=Year,  y=sum_total,  fill=Quarter,  label = dollar(sum_total),  group = group),vjust = 0.5,  check_overlap = T) +    
        geom_col(position="stack", color = "black") +
        geom_text(aes(label=dollar(sum_total)),
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.9)) +  
    stat_summary(fun = sum, aes(label = dollar(..y..),
                                group = Year,
                                vjust = -1), 
                 geom = "text") +    
        scale_y_continuous(labels = label_number_si())

Comment: you see it in Rstudio, then you're meant to copy that code, and paste it here on your SO post.